# Product name on multiple lines

Tags: magento2.4, category-listing, porto-theme

I am using Magento 2.4.2 and the latest porto theme and i would line the product name to be listed on 2 lines and then if still longer then show an ellipsis. I would like to do this anywhere where i have the grid option to display products like the category page and by bestsellers and latest products grid.
I would like to do this with CSS and not hide any text using PHP for SEO reasons.
For example, at the moment i have:

```
This is my long...
```

What i would like is:

```
This is my
long product ...
```

Where the full product name would be "This is my long product name". Maybe i have to use a combination of PHP and CSS but i dont want to limit the string using PHP but i could use it to split the line at a certain point which should match the product width.

EDIT:
I think i need to use:

```
.products-grid .product-item .product-item-details .product-item-name {
    /* autoprefixer: off */
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical !important;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2 !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
  }
```

But when adding this even styles-m-min.css still takes priority and i cant find the correct .less file to edit that. Does anyone know which LESS file as the .product-item-name class in?

Answer (score 0):

word-wrap: break-word:  might help you

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: I tried that, but it didnt seem to perform exactly as i wanted. I could try again incase i messed it up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using some CSS codes.

Magento 2 uses less file so you can also use less type as follows below step.

```
Create new file at Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/source/_module.less
```

Then add

```
 .catalog-product-index {
    .data-grid-cell-content.white-space-preserved {
        white-space: initial;
        inline-size: 250px
    }
}
```

After than run

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```